# Ruby pass self as instance in initialize

Tags: ruby

```
def initialize()
  @attribute = AnotherClass.new(self)
end
```

I am going to ruby from python. In python, I know I can pass self as an object to a function.
Now, I want to pass self to another class's initialize method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just the way you would expect:

```
class A
  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end
end

class B
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize
   @bar = A.new(self)
  end
end

B.new.bar.class #=> A
```